# not be able to remove stopword

Tags: python, nlp, corpus, stop-words

i have stopword list but somehow the program cannot remove the stopword in the corpus

the code i use

```
stop_factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
more_stopword = ['selamat','halo','hallo','hi']
dok_word = ['Dok','dok?', 'dok,', 'dok.', 'dok-', 'dok!', 'dok:', 'dok;', 'dok', 'dok.,','dok,.','dok?.',
            'Dokter','dokter?', 'dokter,', 'dokter.', 'dokter-', 'dokter!', 'dokter:', 'dokter;']
data = stop_factory.get_stop_words()+more_stopword+dok_word

# cleaning
def clean_text(text):
    new_text = []
    text = text.lower() # Lowercase
    # Loop each word in a sentence
    for kata in text.split(): 
        # Keep word not in slang or standard word
        if kata not in std_word_replace: 
            new_text.append(kata) 
        # Replace non-formal word with standard word
        elif kata in std_word_replace:
            new_text+=std_word_replace[kata].split() 
    # Join words without stopwords after stemming
    new_text = ' '.join(
        stemmer.stem(word) for word in new_text if word not in data
    )
    # Remove punctuations
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return new_text
```

and so i aplied to my corpus with this code
`xtrain['question'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))`
, the rows are like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZmnY.png) and taking the example from the first index

words : `'Dok,anak saya sudah imunisasi DPT'`

output : `'dok anak imunisasi dpt'`

the word 'dok' is still there, how do i fix this?

Comment: what is `StopWordRemoverFactory()`? Where is that class defined? Shouldn't you pass the list of stopwords to the stop word remover?

Comment: can you reload check again, i just update the question with extra context

Comment: what is contained in "std_word_replace"?

Comment: its just iterate for slang word to standar word

Comment: I still don't know what is `StopWordRemoverFactory`. You are not importing or defining this anywhere

Comment: its a Sastrawi library for stopword

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create dok_word but you unused it. You also need to double check because text_dok = "dok,anak saya sepertinya" if you just split by the space then the stopword still won't affect.

Comment: can you reload check again, i just update the question with extra context

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the last line, you should use it like `stopwordexample.remove(dok_word)`

```
stop_factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
dok_word = ['Dok','dok?', 'dok,', 'dok.', 'dok-', 'dok!', 'dok:', 'dok;', 'dok', 'dok.,','dok,.','dok?.',
            'Dokter','dokter?', 'dokter,', 'dokter.', 'dokter-', 'dokter!', 'dokter:', 'dokter;']

text_dok = "dok,anak saya sepertinya"
stopwordexample = stop_factory.create_stop_word_remover()
text_dok = stopwordexample.remove(dok_word)
```

Comment: can you reload check again, i just update the question with extra context